# Why isn't my variable being defined?

Tags: python

```
# players stats and elements
player_health = 100
player_attack.earth = 20
player_attack.air =10
player_attack.fire = 15
player_attack.water = 12
ogre_health = 75
ogre_attack = 15

# main code
player_name = input('What is your name, Guardian? ')

print('Hello ' + player_name + ' the Guardian')

player_element = input('Would you like to be the Guardian of Air, Earth, Fire or Water? ')

if player_element == 'Air':
    print('You have been granted the powers of the Air, Guardian.\
You now have the powers of the Wind and Sky.')

if player_element == 'Earth':
    print('You have been granted the powers of the Earth, Guardian.\
You now have the powers of the Earth.')

if player_element == 'Fire':
    print('You have been granted the powers of Fire, Guardian.\
You now have the powers of Fire. Do not destroy as you wish.')

if player_element == 'Water':
    print('You have been granted the powers of Water, Guardian.\
You now have the powers to control the oceans and water.')

print('There is an enemy in the distance! What do you do?')

player_action = input('What do you do ' + player_name + '? ' + 'Type A to attack ')
if player_action == 'A':
   enemy_health = enemy_health - power

print('The enemy\'s health is at ' + str(enemy_health) + ' Keep attacking!')

player_action = input('What do you do ' + player_name + '? ' + 'Type A to attack ')
if player_action == 'A':

    if player_element == 'Water':
        ogre_health = ogre_health - player_attack.water

print('The enemy\'s health is at ' + str(ogre_health) + ' Keep attacking!')
```

This is my code.
It gives me the error `cannot define player_attack.earth`
Why? I defined it. What is the problem here?
I'm using python 3.4.3

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the **full text** of the traceback. Use the `{ }` code formatting button to format your code properly.

Comment: What is `playerAttack`? Is it a class? Does it have a `earth` field already?

Comment: im new to python so i dont know much. this is all of the code

Comment: We don't want *"all of the code"*; create a [mcve]

Comment: im only 13 years old so im new here jeez

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python: Do the tutorial and then try again. You seem to be very confused on how Python works.

Comment: What gave you the idea that you could define a variable name containing a dot?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple, because a variable name cannot have a '.' in it. That would point to a attribute within a class.

You find more details about allowed characters and naming rules here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers